# How to fix "Incorrect syntax near ')'". when there is no ) in the query

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I am attempting to run a query against my database using Dapper, however, an exception is being thrown. The message of the exception is

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

The part of this that is confusing to me is that I have no right parens in my entire query. It used to have some, but I have been simplifying it until I got to this:

```
select i.id as EmployeeReviewId
from @ReviewIds i
```

Which still causes the error.

`@ReviewIds` is a table-valued-parameter that only has one column, an int column named id.

I am calling the function like this:

```
await connection.QueryAsync<FooInfo>(sql, new { reviewIds });
```

where `FooInfo` is an object that has an `EmployeeReviewId` property, and `reviewIds` is an enumerable of `int`.

I have to assume that this is something to do with how I am using Dapper.

Would anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably passing user defined table parameter incorrectly. You have to pass it as DataTable, not as a simple array. A minimal working example is

```
public class FooInfo
{
    public int EmployeeReviewId { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var connection =
            new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=YOUR_DB_NAME;Server=."))
        {
            var result = await connection.QueryAsync<FooInfo>("select i.id as EmployeeReviewId from @ReviewIds i", new
            {
                ReviewIds = CreateTableType(new[] {1, 2, 3})
            });
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }

    private static DataTable CreateTableType(IEnumerable<int> nums)
    {
        var t = new DataTable();
        t.SetTypeName("dbo.ArrayOfInt");
        t.Columns.Add("id");
        foreach (var num in nums)
        {
            t.Rows.Add(num);
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

Where dbo.ArrayOfInt is

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ArrayOfInt AS TABLE  
(  
id int NOT NULL
)
```